# Install Ubuntu 10.04 (Paravirtualization) on CentOS 5 using Xen 

Tags: xen, xenserver

Anyone got instructions on how to install Ubutnu 10.04 (Paravirtualization) on CentOS 5 using Xen?

I was able to install using netboot: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/lucid/main/installer-amd64/current/images/netboot/xen/

Finished the installation but failed to bootup, anyone can help?

Detail:

```
1. Create a new disk with LVM
2. Downlaod vmlinuz & initrd.gz from
http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/lucid/main/installer-amd64/current/images/netboot/xen/
3. /usr/sbin/xm create -c /etc/xen/ubuntu.cfg install=true
4. Format the whole disk as EXT3, mount as /
5. The installer show some warnings (randomly, since they are not repeatable)

Deboostrap warning
Warnings: Couldn't download package libnewt0.52

6. The clicked continue, and retry to install the base system again
7. When prompted to choose the kernel, I cannot find xen related, so I
choose linux-generic
8. Everything alright, the installer quit and system halt.
9. I launch the VM using  /usr/sbin/xm create -c /etc/xen/ubuntu.cfg, it show
Error: Bootloader isn't executable

p.s. ubuntu.cfg
==============
name = "Ubuntu"
kernel = "/root/ubuntu/vmlinuz"
ramdisk = "/root/ubuntu/initrd.gz"
vif = [ "mac=00:13:1e:6e:23:e2,bridge=xenbr0" ]
disk = [ "phy:/dev/vg0/ubuntu,xvda,w" ]
==============
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found some howtos, try to check it out, maybe it will help you http://drup.org/how-install-ubuntu-vm-under-centosred-hat-xen and the second one http://dev.osso.nl/herman/blog/2006/12/24/ubuntu-bootmenu-too-shiny-for-xen-with-hvm/ (it;s a little bit old but maybe will tell you more).
Executing this command

```
ls -l /usr/lib/xen-tool
```

should give you a list of all distributions that you can install. I hope some of these informations will point you closer to solve your problem. I am always installing only debian as guest so I never had these problems.